# How would you translate "minority languages"

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, solicitud-de-término

I am trying to use a politically correct term to refer to any language (also known as dialect) used by a minority group in LA. Some ideas I have are *idiomas de minorías* or *lenguas indígenas*, but I don't know if there is a better term for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use "[lenguas minoritarias](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lengua_minoritaria)", to refer to languages spoken by minority groups, or "minorías lingüísticas," to refer to the groups speaking those languages.

Answer (score 3):

I expand that besides the proposed "minoritarias", you can also use

> **Lenguas de minorías**  ([source](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22lenguas+de+minor%C3%ADas%22) in Google Books)

Comment: I guess that works; the other two options seem more mellifluous (to me).